# gitolite/git: how can I automatically populate the git pre-commit/pre-push hook

Tags: git, githooks, gitolite

I would like to automatically populate the .git/hook/pre-push/pre-commit file with custom content whenever someone clone my repositories.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

`git` won't do this on it's own - by design. Not sure about `gitolite`, as I'm not familiar with it.

One way you could accomplish this would be by distributing a custom clone script that runs `git clone` and then creates/copies the hook scripts into the proper location, possibly getting them from the repository itself, or from a HTTP or FTP server, or hard-coding the hook contents in the script.

Comment: Gitolite is purely server side; it has no client side presence.